# Get value from selectOption [Boolean] in selectList

Tags: selectlist, selectoption

I need to get the boolean from a selectList. 
For example I have the following code.

```
<apex:selectList id="chooseRule" value="{!}" size="1">
                            <apex:selectOption itemEscaped="false" itemValue="bContains" itemLabel="Contains"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemEscaped="false" itemValue="bStart" itemLabel="Start with"/>
                            <apex:selectOption itemEscaped="false" itemValue="bNotEqual" itemLabel="Not Equal to"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
```

How can I show in my code behind, something like:

```
If(bContains == true){ do something}
```

Something like that?. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to bind your `apex:selectList` to a string input:

```
<apex:selectList id="chooseRule" value="{!selectedChooseRule}" ...
```

In your Apex Code, you could use getters to define your Boolean values:

```
public String selectedChooseRule { get; set; }
public Boolean bContainsRule { get { return selectedChooseRule == 'bContains'; } }
```